# Two Google maps API SupportMapFragments in one activity. One I cannot move with. Android

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

So I have this situation. I have one activity with content FrameLayout. Then I create two SupportMapFragments and add it into content frame. Of course is visible only one at time and when I want to see another one then I hide the first and show the second. But what hapens is that I can move only with the first map and not with another. Is that bug or is there something that I need to do differentely than only show/hide fragments?

Thanks a lot :)

**EDIT 1:**

Here is sample code with what I am basicaly doing:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment1, mapFragment2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment1 = new SupportMapFragment();
    mapFragment2 = new SupportMapFragment();

    FragmentTransa ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.mapFrame, mapFragment1);
    ft.add(R.id.mapFrame, mapFragment2);
    ft.hide(mapFragment2);
    ft.commit();
}

private void switch() {       
   FragmentTransa ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   if (mapFragment1.isVisible()) {
      ft.hide(mapFragment1);
      ft.show(mapFragment2);
   } else {
      ft.hide(mapFragment2);
      ft.show(mapFragment1);
   }
   ft.commit();
}
```

I'm calling switch() on button click and I'm able to move only with that mam that is created the first.

Comment: do you mind to show your current code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mind to show my code, but it is little more extensive. But I'll edit in few mins what I am bassicaly doing in general :)